# How should left and right hand by synchronized in Chopin Nocturne in C# Minor

Tags: piano, technique, rhythm, cadenza

I have a question about which notes on the right-hand match with which notes on the left hand.

[image: Chopin Nocturne in C# Minor, mm. 59-end]

Comment: Related question on the same piece, with a similar answer: [how to coordinate hands when playing very fast](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/108994/how-to-coordinate-hands-when-playing-very-fast)

Answer (score 0):

These kinds of ornamental runs do not need to be played in a metrically exact way, so you can match up notes in a way you find musically pleasing.

As a general, personal rule, I like to start runs slower and finish faster. So for the first run, I'd group the notes 2+3+3+3 against the four left-hand notes.

```
X: 0
T: Nocturne in C# Minor
T: m. 60, beats 3-4
C: Chopin
M: none
K: C# minor
L: 1/16
V:V1
V:V2 clef=bass
%%score (V1 | V2)
[V:V1] AB (3cde (3fed (3cBA |
[V:V2] C,2F,2D2C2 |
```

However, for the second run, because it's moving into the rallentando and represents a "cooling off" of the piece, I would tend to play slower toward the end. Either 3+4+3+3 or 3+3+4+3.

```
X: 0
T: Nocturne in C# Minor
T: m. 61, beats 3-4, version 1
C: Chopin
M: none
K: C# minor
L: 1/16
V:V1
V:V2 clef=bass
%%score (V1 | V2)
[V:V1] (3ABc d/2e/2f/2g/2 (3fed (3cBA |
[V:V2] C,2F,2D2C2 |
```

OR

```
X: 0
T: Nocturne in C# Minor
T: m. 61, beats 3-4, version 2
C: Chopin
M: none
K: C# minor
L: 1/16
V:V1
V:V2 clef=bass
%%score (V1 | V2)
[V:V1] (3ABc (3def g/2f/2e/2d/2 (3cBA |
[V:V2] C,2F,2D2C2 |
```