# question about distributing notes over long run in Chopin C# Minor Nocturne

Tags: piano, technique

This is from Chopin's Noctrune in C sharp minor. The run is so long, is there a technique for how should left and right hand by synchronized for this part?

[image: Chopin Nocturne in C# minor, m. 59]

Comment: Please note that the technique is described in the answer to the second listed duplicate question: [How should left and right hand by synchronized in Chopin Nocturne in C# Minor](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/109164/how-should-left-and-right-hand-by-synchronized-in-chopin-nocturne-in-c-minor/109165#109165).